# Database (EF) structure question - inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I realize this skirts dangerously close to asking for opinions. But I think this is ok.

My question on the below is which approach will Entity Framework handle best. For example AsSplitQuery() can't handle some ThenInclude() calls with the way I presently have this (#1 below). So to repeat, please no opinions in the answers, just what EF problems will I hit with each.

In my app (for managing volunteers) it has Jobs and Events. A Job has no set time and usually no specific location. An example would be marketing a booth that will be at a street fair. And Event has a specific time, including sometimes shifts, and usually a specific location. An example would be staffing the booth.

And major constraint. A volunteer can signup for a Job or Event. There is a Signup table. So there's a 1:many relationship from Job/Event to Signup. And the FK in signup pointing to the parent Job/Event - if those are distinct tables that won't work.

Probably 95% or more of the items are Events. In large part because many Events are reoccurring while a Job may be "4 hours data entry/week" but that is one ongoing Job, not a reoccurring Job.

From a programming point of view Event is a subclass of Job. The question is how should I structure this in EF:

Update per @IvanStoev - #1 and #2 have significant limitations in EF.

1. <s>Declare an abstract base class of Effort. Then Job (which adds nothing to Effort) and Event are subclasses.</s>
2. <s>No base class, declare Job and Event is a subclass of Job.</s>
3. Only the class Event, where all the "event only" properties are nullable.
4. Have distinct Job and Event classes where the Event class has a Job property for the Job elements.
5. Have a Job class and it has a When property that is the additional properties in Event. This property is null for a "job." In this case, I can call `builder.OwnsOne(org => org.When)` so it's in the same record (more efficient queries) but can be null.
6. Have distinct Job and Event classes. Both implement the IJob interface.

I've taken approach #1 but EF implements it sort-of like approach #3 where the database has an Effort table and no Event or Job table. I think part of the reason EF does this, and it's a major constraint, is these table(s) have a 1:many relationship with children records.

Comment: *"I've taken approach #1 but EF implements it sort-of like approach #3 where the database has an Effort table and no Event or Job table.*" You are mixing the concepts here. First is how your inheritance model looks like, and second is how EF Core implements is in the database. And for the second, they provide 3 strategies, all explained in the [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) section of the official EF Core documentation, with their pros and cons (here you are referring to TPH which is just the default if you don't configure other).

Comment: It should be enough to help you make the decision which one to use (if use inheritance at all), I see no reason of replicating all that info here. Same for `OwnsOne` - owned entity types just by default are stored in the same table. But they could be stored in a separate table as well. While the "regular" entities by default are opposite - references stored in a separate table, but can be configured to go to the same table (the so called "table splitting"). So really this is a physical storage mapping, and the primary problem in your case is the logical model.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes but... I'm finding that the TPH is limiting some use of ThenInclude(). So you're right that the programmatic design is distinct from the DB schema. But the DB schema structure does impose limitations. I'm trying to avoid limitations. And get the best performance.

Comment: I don't think TPH is limiting `Include`s. If you mean your previous question, you just have wrong model from both OO and relational POV. Anytime `A` has a property of type `B`, it implies `B` having collection of `A`. In your case, `Effort` has parent `Organization`, so `Organization` should have collection of `Effort`, not collection of `Event` or `Job`. It will contain both events and jobs, that's it, anything deriving from `Effort`. This is called polymorphic collection. The one you are trying is just a filtered subset of it, and this is something EF cannot provide you via navigation.

Comment: @IvanStoev That makes sense. And is also a reason not to use approach #1 or #2. Thank you for this point.